# How do you fulfill "film shoot" in pocket planes events

Tags: pocket-planes

Please help me I love pocket planes but cannot figure out how on earth to fulfill events please help anyone good at pocket planes. Pease specifically help me on completing "film shoot" I am having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the other answers here are correct but incomplete. **You fulfill events by delivering 1000 cargo/passengers to the specified destination during the event in progress.** Because it is nearly impossible to get more than a few hundred (at the most) during a single 12-hour span, this means that you will have to wait for some events to come around several times before you have finished fulfilling the requirement. At the end, you receive 15 bux.

Strategically, if you wait for an event to take place at a class 3 airport, you can use larger, faster airplanes and thus deliver more items within the allotted time period.

For a global event, which has items highlighted in blue, and which goes for 3.5 days (instead of 12 hours), you must be a member of a flight crew and deliver (usually) at least 50 cargo/passengers in order to be eligible for prizes (the exact amount of required cargo/passengers is located in flight crew --> prizes). The prizes you receive for global events vary from event to event. Sometimes you receive bux, sometimes airplane parts, sometimes entire airplanes. However, your flight crew must rank within the top X number of deliveries in order to win prizes.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep sending people and cargo to the place specified by the event. "Film Shoot" event, specifically, makes most passengers and cargo "rare" ones which usually give out bux but in this case don't. To complete, it just load all the passenger/cargo with a costume or difference and fly.

You probably won't get more than 50, and 100 at the most (believe me, here). Then you just wait for that event to come up again and do this again. Eventually, you will fulfill that event. In the meantime, try other events and keep many going. Unlike Nimblebit's other populat Tiny Tower, it is unwise to focus on one event solely as you could be waiting days, weeks or months for that event to come by at one of the airports you have.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of is that there are two kinds of events in Pocket Planes that appear in the Events listing.  Most of them are local events that merely increase traffic to the destination listed and have no special prize.  For example, "Film Shoot in Chicago" would result in more people jobs (with passengers who look like actors) and cargo jobs (things like movie cameras or film.)  For those, you can take advantage of the added traffic if you already have the airport or want to add it but there is no additional benefit.

The top event listed on the "Events" page is generally the Global Event, listed in blue.  For that, the general approach is the same but if you participate in a flight crew (for example, TOUCHARCADE or REDDIT generally have many people) then you may get the additional listed prize (bux, random plane part, or sometimes a complete plane, usually of a type not available in the market.)  For that, your prize level is determined by the total of all crew members and whether or not you met the threshold (usually 50 jobs in the allocated time.)  Crews such as TOUCHARCADE have many people contributing and generally get one of the top 3 spots so as long as you do enough to get the 50 job minimum, you'll get the same prize as the dedicated folks on the crew who do 150+ jobs for the Global Event.